# How to modify the default asp.net mvc css to have the menu item starting from left

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have created a new asp.net mvc 4 web application. but the current main menu, which contain the following links "Home" "About" "Contact" is showing at the right-side of the screen. so how I can change the float to be left instead of right ?
I tried the following but it did not work:-

```
 /* menu */
    nav {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
     clear: both;
    float: left;   

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing `clear: both;`

Answer (score 2):

If u notice in _sitelayout.cshtml, ur nav is in div with class float-right. Change it to float-left. Also in ur css, check for ul#menu has property text-align : right; remove this property. See below screen shot after the changes.

[image]